# Changing date objects date using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to just alter the date of a date object and leave the time as is.
For example I have a display of dates that are dynamically generated based on a week long of dates. So starting at today's date and showing all the dates in between today until the same day a week from now. This is all setup and when you click on one of those days I need a way to update a variable holding a current date to the date that represents the day that was clicked on.

The variable currentDate holds an object like this.

```
var currentDate = {Thu Oct 06 2011 08:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)}
```

So the question is can I update just the Thu Oct 06 2011 part of the object with my newly clicked date while still keeping the time part of the object intact.

Thanks

Comment: `var d = new Date(); d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1 % 12)` <- example of month increment

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two more functions you can use here to set the month and year as well:

```
currentDate.setDate(15);  //sets day of month to 15
currentDate.setFullYear(2010);  //sets year to 2012
currentDate.setMonth(2); //sets month to February
```

Use a jquery selector to get the values then pass them to a function that looks something like this:

```
function InputChanged(){
var day=$('#day').val();
var month=$('#month').val();
var year=$('#year').val();
UpdateTime(day,month,year);
}

function UpdateTime(day,month,year){
currentDate.setDate(day);
currentDate.setMonth(month);
currentDate.setYear(year);
};
```

This of course depends on your inputs having classes of 'day', 'month',and 'year'.  If you are collecting this information from a single input you will need to parse through it.

Comment: Ok this sounds promising but how would I get those values from the pressed button that has an object with the date in it and set that date only to the currentDate without altering its time. I understand I can use these methods but these are hard coded values sent into them.

Comment: Thanks Joshua for the updated post. I'm not getting these dates form an input or html element. The are actually a unique date object for each button. So I would need to extract it from the date object like the example above then add it back to another date object thats stored in the currentDate variable. I just don't need to manipulate the time. So if date is like date = {Mon Oct 05 2011 08:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)} could I do date.day value or something like that

Comment: as you see above date.getDate() returns the day of month so you could do currentDate.setDate(date.getDate());